# load checkboxes in fixed columns

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am loading checkboxes dynamically from knockout observable array. But it is loading only 1 checkbox per row. I want to load checkbox in 4 columns per row.

```
<table border = "1">
<tbody data-bind="foreach: dataOne">
    <tr>
        <td ><input style="display: inline-block;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: name1" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/134/)

I tried using inline-block but doesnt help. I read something about control group but not sure how to implement it.

Someone please point me in right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the data as follow :

```
var groups = [];
var groupSize = 4
var group = [];
// create full groups 
for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
     group.push(data[index])
     if (group.length == groupSize) {
         groups.push(group);
         group = [];
     }
}
// adds the rest
if (group.length) {
     groups.push(group);
}
```

and use this view :

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: dataOne">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="foreach: $data">
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: name1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/138/)

You could also create an computed that groups the data in automatically as [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/148/) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: dataOne">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="foreach: row">
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: name1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and in your *js* script:

```
 var data1 = [{
     row: [{
         name1: "one"
     }, {
         name1: "two"
     }, {
         name1: "three"
     }, {
         name1: "three"
     }]
 }, {
     row: [{
         name1: false
     }, {
         name1: true
     }, {
         name1: true
     }, {
         name1: false
     }]
 }];
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TaF8W/135/)'s the live example.

Comment: Not sure why you added true, false and i dont get data in format you have written

Comment: Just to illustrate the position where the checkboxes are being rendered. `one`, `two`, `three` are not valid values for the `checked:` property. `false` and `true` are.